# show spinner before adding widget android

Tags: android, widget, spinner

For a widget I am creating for the Android OS, I want the user to first select a certain option from a Spinner. Just like when you add a shortcut to the homescreen.

Is that possible or do you have to start an Activity?
If it is possible, can anyone explain how to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Spinner` widgets do not exist on their own -- you have to have them in an `Activity`. Android's app widget framework supports the notion of a configuration activity that is automatically launched when somebody chooses your widget. Just put your `Spinner` in there.